# Apache child died for unknown reason

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

For a long times i saw such errors on FreeBSD9.1 (Apache 2.2) server

```
 # dmesg
    pid 69320 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 69307 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 69416 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 10
    pid 93318 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 93295 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 93289 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 93965 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
    pid 93993 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11
```

After searches found related problem:
http://dready.org/blog/2010/07/04/httpd-exited-on-signal-11-solved/
and couple of others recommends to disable mbstring. I haven't try this because i need mbstring in phpmyadmin. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php
i was using php5.3 and today upgraded to 5.4.19 and this error still exists. Actually Apache working fine and seems like spawning child again after exiting.

Answer (score 1):

**Where to get more precise information?**

You can find more information on the main Apache error log, the one defined in httpd.conf outside any  block.

**A similar issue, a working solution but no warranty this is your issue**

The solution you've found in [this blog post](http://dready.org/blog/2010/07/04/httpd-exited-on-signal-11-solved/) describes one system administrator who experimented an issue and solved it.

Why do you assume this is your problem too? Can't softwares quit for several reasons?

**mod_php, PHP as CGI and php-fpm**

If really you think your issue is related to PHP, you have three ways to use PHP with Apache :

- with mod_php, like the [this blog post](http://dready.org/blog/2010/07/04/httpd-exited-on-signal-11-solved/) author. PHP interpreter is loaded when you start Apache and ready to execute script
- as CGI, like on legacy and current shared hosting environments, generally with a patched SuEXEC for hosting facilities, stuff like suphp for the smaller needs. Each script is independently executed by PHP, Apache gets the output and prints it.
- with php-fpm for current dedicated hosting and cutting edge shared hosting environments. A FastCGI implementation for PHP, with a pool of processes with PHP interpreter already loaded in memory ready to execute the PHP code. Picking this solution will give you better performances than CGI.

If you choose to use php-fpm, [the Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) contains tips and installation notes.

Once you switched your config in CGI mode or php-fpm, as PHP code is executed outside Apache:

- if Apache still quits, the processes bugs come from another reason, not related to PHP.
- if Apache is okay, congratulations, it were a mod_php issue, now you're fine.